# InfoPath Drop-Down Listbox Manual Choices Repeating

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

So I have a simple drop-down listbox in my InfoPath form that basically looks like this:

```
Select:
    Choice 1
    Choice 2
    Choice 3
```

The choices are manually entered and it works for everyone, except for this particular user it's displayed like this:

```
Select:
    Choice 1
    Choice 1
    Choice 1
```

The control and values are manually entered and not tied to any external data sources or rules.  Does anyone have any idea?  It does not matter if you are creating a new form or open existing ones.

Comment: Has that user tried it from another computer, or has another logged-in user tried it on that computer? Are the forms saved locally or online somewhere? If saved online (like in SharePoint or somewhere else) are they opened directly from there, or downloaded first and then opened locally?

Comment: The user had tried it from a different workstation with same results.  The form is saved online at a SharePoint Form Library.  It's downloaded then opened locally.

Comment: No script is used? Does this one user have a different type of profile than other users? (roaming, local, etc.)

Comment: No scripting at all.. We're pretty locked down.  Not sure which profile. I'll have to check and get back on Monday.